# How to change the address of a pointer of a parameter in a function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I created a function to change the value of `*a`, but it remains unchanged after the function `fun` has been executed.

Here's my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(int *b){
    int *c = new int;
    *c = 4;
    b = c;
}
int main(){
    int *a = new int;
    *a = 2;
    fun(a);
    cout << *a << endl; // the output is 2 but I want it be 4
    return 0;
}
```

I want `*a` be `4` in function `fun`

Comment: Do you want `*a` to be 4 because `a` points to the `new int` allocated in `main` whose value is 4? Or do you want `*a` to be 4 because `a` points to the `new int` allocated in `fun` whose value is 4? Do you just want `fun` to do `*b = 4;`?

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways, first the C++ way is to have a mutable (non-`const`) reference:

```cpp
void fun(int& b) {
   b = 4;
}

// Calling
int x = 0;
fun(x);
```

Then the classic C way is to use a regular pointer:

```c
void fun(int* b) {
   *b = 4;
}

// Calling
int x = 0;
fun(&x);
```

The reference approach is better because there's less syntax chaff both in calling the function, and in the function's implementation. There's also no risk you might get `nullptr`, a reference *will* be defined.

> Note: Your use of `new` here has unintended consequences, like leaking memory. When you allocate with `new` you are responsible for releasing that memory.

Answer (score 0):

In your function instead of `b=c` you should write
`*b = *c` to change the value stored at the address pointed by `b`.
That is the reason your function does not work as desired.

In case of any query please feel free to clarify.

Comment: @zhuchengyang Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 b = c;
```

b is pointer, this operation makes b points to the address c represents. you do not change the value located on the address of 'a'

```
 *b = *c;
```

This is the right